# Monodroid obfuscate

Tags: .net, dll, xamarin.android, obfuscation

I have developed a monodroid application and I want to know the best way to obfuscate the app.  I tried obfuscating Dll files with net obfuscators like dotfuscator and xenocode without success.
I put my dll files in the apk package but we get execution errors or directly get errors obfuscating.

Anyone can help me?  Unfortunately there is not documentation about this for monodroid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post on the mailing list says that Xenocode works when metadata reduction is disabled: http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Any-obfuscator-working-with-Mono-for-Android-td5050825.html

This one should work as well:
http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm

Comment: Few days after, I obfuscated my solution with Xenocode with some difficulty